# Using an int in another method

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, methods, integer

Hey guys I need to use an Int called points from method ValidateAns in a Method Main. I searched around the net and people said I should do ValidateAns(points), however it does not work for me, Im not sure if  I'm doing it wrong or I should use some other way to do it

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const int QuestionNumbers = 10;
    char[] Answear = new char[QuestionNumbers];

    Question[] MCQ = new Question[QuestionNumbers];

    MCQ[0] = new Question(Slaughterhouse);
    MCQ[1] = new Question(Frankenstein);
    MCQ[2] = new Question(Things);
    MCQ[3] = new Question(Jane);
    MCQ[4] = new Question(Kill);
    MCQ[5] = new Question(Beloved);
    MCQ[6] = new Question(Gatsby);
    MCQ[7] = new Question(Catcher);
    MCQ[8] = new Question(Pride);
    MCQ[9] = new Question(Nineteen);

    for (int i = 0; i < QuestionNumbers; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Question {0}", i + 1);
        Answear[i] = MCQ[i]();
        ValidateAns(i + 1, Answear[i]);
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

}

static void ValidateAns(int Nbr, char Ans)
{
    int points= 0;

    switch (Nbr)
    {
        case 1:

            if (Ans == 'b' || Ans == 'B')
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Good Answear");
                points++;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Wrong Answer - The right answer was (B)");
                break;
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can just return `bool` from `ValidateAns` to indicate if the answer was correct. In the loop logic, you will add 1 to a counter of points if the `bool` was true.

Comment: I think this question should not have the tag [visual-studio-2012]!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I restructured the members you gave us.

Think about naming convention,  if you're going to validate something you would need to return a Boolean or bool to state whether the answer was give is valid or not. see `IsValidAnswer()`. When writing members that return a bool think of using a linking verb. Is, Has, Will.

when you compare the type `char` you can use `char.ToUpperInvariant(char val)`, so you dont have to compare your answer to too different cases of the same character.

i hope this helps, check out the comments in the code. There is a nugget in there that you will love as a developer. :) have a good day

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const int QuestionNumbers = 10;
    var Answer = new char[QuestionNumbers];

    Question[] MCQ = new Question[QuestionNumbers];


    MCQ[0] = new Question(Slaughterhouse);
    MCQ[1] = new Question(Frankenstein);
    MCQ[2] = new Question(Things);
    MCQ[3] = new Question(Jane);
    MCQ[4] = new Question(Kill);
    MCQ[5] = new Question(Beloved);
    MCQ[6] = new Question(Gatsby);
    MCQ[7] = new Question(Catcher);
    MCQ[8] = new Question(Pride);
    MCQ[9] = new Question(Nineteen);

    for (int i = 0; i < QuestionNumbers; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Question {0}", i + 1);
        Answer[i] = MCQ[i]();

        // return bool since you want to validate an answer.
        var result =  IsValidAnswer(i + 1, Answer[i]);

                            // this is an if/else conditional statment, its called a ternary expression
        Console.WriteLine(result ? "Answer is valid" : "Answer is not valid");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}


private static bool IsValidAnswer(int Nbr, char Ans)
{
    // if you really wanted to use a method. 
    var correctAnswer = default(char);
    switch (Nbr)
    {
        case 1:
            correctAnswer = 'b';
            break;
        case 2:
            //.. 
            break;
    }
    return char.ToUpperInvariant(Ans) == char.ToUpperInvariant(correctAnswer);
}
```

Comment: The answer helped a lot, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

define your function as

```
static int ValidateAns(int Nbr, char Ans)
```

and return the points value with `return points;`

then call it with something like

```
int p=ValidateAns(i + 1, Answear[i]);
```